# Can't switch images with Slick Slider / Twig

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, loops, twig, advanced-custom-fields

EDIT

Hi everyone,

I use Slick Slider and a twig loop for my ACF PRO gallery, but i have a problem.. I actually have my first image of the gallery but i can't switch to the others with the arrows and i don't understand why..

```
{% block content %}

<div class="thing" id="wrapper">
    {% for image in post.meta('images') %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ Image(image) }}" />
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thing').slick({
            arrows: true,
    });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Could you please help me guys ?

Comment: does the `html` output contains multiple image to start with?

Comment: I use a gallery of ACF Pro called 'images', this is where are my images

Comment: I mean, does the rendered output of your `twig` template contains multiple `<img />'-tags?

Comment: Absolutely yes, i have 10 images in my gallery and i see all of them when i click on "view the source code of the page"